# Adding loading bar for simulation web app

Tags: reactjs

I've made a simulation web app with React. If the user chooses certain simulation parameters, the simulation can take a long time. Of course, I want to add a loading screen so users know something's happening. I have everything ready & working, except that I cannot get the state to update (or maybe it's just that the page isn't being repainted?) until after the simulation is completed.

Specifically, if a button press calls `startSim` as written below, no state change is visible on the page.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        is_loading: false,
        sim_data: []
    }

    startSim() {
        this.setState({is_loading: true})
        this.runSim()
    }

    runSim() {
        // generate data
        this.setState({is_loading: false, sim_data: new_data})
    }

    render() {
        // set up input, run button & graph to display results
    }
}
```

Here's what I've tried:

- I have found the `forceUpdate` function, but the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#forceupdate) seems to urge against its use.
- I've also tried to use promises without luck, as follows.

```js
    async startSim() {
        this.setState({is_loading: true})
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(this.runSim()))
    }
```

- I thought `flushSync` would solve my problem, but it strangely it is not actually forcing rendering before continuing. I'll have the inspect tool up, and I see no class update in the HTML.

```js
    startSim() {
        flushSync(() => {this.setState({is_loading: true});})
        this.runSimulation()
    }
```

I can't imagine my desired behavior is very unique, so I'm hoping to get help to see what I'm missing. Lots of googling and lots of ChatGPT have not helped me solve my issue.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use functional React components?

Comment: @Aleksandar sorry, can you explain how those could solve this issue? I've used functions with react but only to render output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using `setTimeout` solves my problem. An embarrassingly straightforward solution.

```js
startSim() {
    this.setState({is_loading: true});
    setTimeout(() => {this.runSimulation()}, 1)
}
```